# What do people mean when they say dfbetas in glms

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, diagnostic

I will follow the notation in the following article in this question

Williams, D. (1987). Generalized Linear Model Diagnostics Using the Deviance and Single Case Deletions. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C (Applied Statistics), 36(2), 181-191. doi:10.2307/2347550

My impression is that when people talk about dfbeta in Generalized linear models (GLMs) they mean is the following one step approximation from a iterative weighted least squares problem

$$\begin{align*}
\\
%
r_{pi} &= \frac{y_i - \mu_i}{\sqrt{v_i(1-h_i)}} \\
%
\text{dfbeta}(i) & =  
  \sqrt{w_i}(1-h_i)^{-1/2}r_{pi}(X^\top WX)^{-1}x_i \\ 
  &= \frac{\left(g^{-1}\right)'(\eta_i)(y_i-\mu_i)}{v_i(1-h_i)}R^{-1}R^{-\top}x_i \\
%
\text{dfbeta}(i) & \approx \widehat{\beta} - \widehat{\beta}_{(i)} 
\end{align*}$$

where

$$
\eta_i = \widehat{\beta}^\top x_i, \quad
v_i = \phi v(\eta_i), \quad
\mu_i=g(\eta_i), \quad
w_i = v_i^{-1}\left(g^{-1}\right)'(\eta_i)^2
$$

where $v$ is the function which multplied by the dispersion parameter, $\phi$, yields the variance of $y_i$ given covariates $x_i$, $g$ is the link function, $w_i$ are the usual working weights, $W$ is a diagonal matrix with $w_i$s in the diagonal and $h_i$ is the $i$th diagonal entry of the hat matrix. Lastly, $R$ is the $R$ matrix in the QR decomposition $QR = \sqrt{W}X$. This leads to my first question

**Is the above also what you usually refer to as dbetas?**

The reason I am asking is since this does not seem to be what I get from the `dfbeta` function  in the `stats` package in R yields. Though,`?dfbeta` states that

> Values for generalized linear models are approximations, as described
>   in Williams (1987) (except that Cook's distances are scaled as F
>   rather than as chi-square values). The approximations can be poor when
>   some cases have large influence.

with a reference to [the aforementioned article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347550). I have implemented the dfbeta in on page 183 of the article. However, this does not yield the result of a `dfbeta` call in. Here is my code and examples

```
> glm_diagnostics <- function(model, na.action = na.pass){
+   #####
+   # Get elements from model for later
+   eta  <- model$linear.predictors
+   mu   <- model$fitted.values
+   fam  <- model$family
+   data <- model$data
+   
+   #####
+   # Find design matrix
+   
+   ## From predict.lm
+   tt <- terms(model)
+   Terms <- delete.response(tt)
+   m <- model.frame(Terms, model$data, na.action = na.action, 
+                    xlev = model$xlevels)
+   if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses"))) 
+     .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
+   X <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts.arg = model$contrasts)
+   offset <- rep(0, nrow(X))
+   if (!is.null(off.num <- attr(tt, "offset"))) 
+     for (i in off.num) offset <- 
+       offset + eval(attr(tt, "variables")[[i + 1]], data)
+   if (!is.null(model$call$offset)) 
+     offset <- offset + eval(model$call$offset, data)
+   ## End from predict.lm
+   
+   # sanity check
+   stopifnot(all(drop(X %*% model$coefficients + offset) == eta))
+   
+   ##### 
+   # Compute values for later computation
+   dispersion <- summary(model)$dispersion
+   vars <- fam$variance(mu) * dispersion
+   hats <- hatvalues(model)
+   d_mu_d_eta <- fam$mu.eta(eta)
+   
+   r_p <- (model$y - mu) / sqrt(vars * (1 - hats))
+   wts <- model$prior.weights * d_mu_d_eta^2 / vars
+   # Notice: could use model$weights instead
+   
+   #####
+   # Compute dfbeta as in Williams (1987)
+   dfbeta. <- ((sqrt(wts / (1 - hats)) * r_p)) * X
+   
+   cov1 <- vcov(model) / dispersion # vcov is scalled by dispersion 
+   R. <- qr.R(model$qr)
+   cov2 <- chol2inv(R.)
+   
+   # sanity check
+   stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(cov2, unname(cov1))))
+   
+   # back to computing dfbeta.
+   dfbeta. <- tcrossprod(dfbeta., cov1)
+   
+   #####
+   # equivalent formula
+   alt <- (d_mu_d_eta * (y - mu) / (vars * (1 - hats))) * X
+   alt <- tcrossprod(alt, cov1)
+   
+   # sanity check
+   stopifnot(isTRUE(all.equal(alt, dfbeta.)))
+   
+   return(list(dfbeta = dfbeta., 
+               dfbeta_w_dispersion = dfbeta. * dispersion))
+ }
> 
> # simulate simple data set
> set.seed(54109320)
> n <- 200
> x <- runif(n)
> lp <- -1 + x
> 
> # gaussian model
> y <- lp + rnorm(n)
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian())
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.9388775   1.0608895 
> 
> tmp <- glm_diagnostics(fit)
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta, dfbeta(fit))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.05469219"
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta_w_dispersion, dfbeta(fit))
[1] TRUE
> 
> # binary outcomes
> y <- (1 + exp(-lp))^-1 > runif(n)
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial())
> fit$coefficients
(Intercept)           x 
  -1.184522    1.008690 
> 
> tmp <- glm_diagnostics(fit)
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta, dfbeta(fit))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.1756459"
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta_w_dispersion, dfbeta(fit)) # dispersion = 1 so no need
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.1756459"
> 
> # poisson outcomes
> y <- rpois(n, exp(lp))
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = poisson())
> 
> tmp <- glm_diagnostics(fit)
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta, dfbeta(fit))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.3012705"
> all.equal(tmp$dfbeta_w_dispersion, dfbeta(fit)) # dispersion = 1 so no need
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.3012705"
```

As shown above, the results are as expected for the linear model only when I multiply with the dispersion paramter unlike in the formulas I show earlier. Further, I cannot get the same results for the nonlinear models. Thus,

**Why is there a difference?**

Shouldn't the *"[v]alues for generalized linear models [be] approximations, as described in Williams (1987) (except that Cook's distances are scaled as F rather than as chi-square values)."* Further, this motivates question

**Are there other formulas for dfbetas that people use? If so, which of them preferable?**

Sorry ahead of times if there is a bug in the above code, if I misread the article or similar errors on my side.

## Update

To the question

> **Why is there a difference?**

The difference is that `dfbeta` uses the deviance residuals instead of the Pearson residuals. I.e.,

$$ \text{dfbeta}(i) =  
  \frac{\sqrt{w_i}r_{di}}{1 - h_i}(X^\top WX)^{-1}x_i $$

where $r_{di}$ is the $i$th observation's deviance residual. I show this below. My to other question though still remains.

```
> new_func <- function(fit){
+   ws <- weighted.residuals(fit)
+   stopifnot( # equal to deviance residuals since we did not use the weight 
+              # argument
+     all(ws == residuals(fit, type = "deviance")))
+   
+   Q. <- qr.Q(fit$qr)
+   R. <- qr.R(fit$qr)
+   vcov. <- chol2inv(R.)
+   hats <- hatvalues(fit)
+   
+   (ws / (1 - hats)) * Q. %*% R. %*% vcov. # QR = \sqrt(W) X
+ }
> 
> # simulate simple data set
> set.seed(54109320)
> n <- 200
> x <- runif(n)
> lp <- -1 + x
> 
> # gaussian model
> y <- lp + rnorm(n)
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = gaussian())
> all.equal(new_func(fit), dfbeta(fit), check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
> 
> # binary outcomes
> y <- (1 + exp(-lp))^-1 > runif(n)
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = binomial())
> all.equal(new_func(fit), dfbeta(fit), check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
> 
> # poisson outcomes
> y <- rpois(n, exp(lp))
> fit <- glm(y ~ x, family = poisson())
> all.equal(new_func(fit), dfbeta(fit), check.attributes = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This seems like a question w/ substantial statistical content to me, even if it is asked in terms of R code. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: If it helps you can find out what R does in stats:::dfbeta.lm which in turn leads you to lm.influence I am afraid I am not enough of an expert on dfbetas to offer you an answer.